# Trying to figure out what this MEF Composition error means

Tags: c#, winforms, mef

I have a question about the following exception I received trying to complete a call to `.ComposeParts(this)`:

> The composition produced a single
>   composition error. The root cause is
>   provided below. Review the
>   CompositionException.Errors property
>   for more detailed information.
>
> 1) The export
>   'CustomersModule.CustomerMenu
>   (ContractName="ModLibrary.IMenu")' is
>   not assignable to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[ModLibrary.IMenu,
>   ModLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]'.
>
> Resulting in: Cannot set import
>   'ModAppWorks.Host.Menus
>   (ContractName="ModLibrary.IMenu")' on
>   part 'ModAppWorks.Host'. Element:
>   ModAppWorks.Host.Menus
>   (ContractName="ModLibrary.IMenu") --> 
>   ModAppWorks.Host

There is a part there that seems like the error means that `IMenu` must implement `IEnumerable`. Here is my composition code:

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Host host = new Host();
        host.Run();
    }
}

class Host
{
    #region Init
    public Host()
    { }
    #endregion

    #region Functions
    public void Run()
    {
        Compose();

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new AppHost());
    }

    private void Compose()
    {
        var agrCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        var dirCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.GetDirectoryName
            (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "..\\..\\..\\Extensions", "*.dll");
        var asmCatalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        agrCatalog.Catalogs.Add(dirCatalog);
        agrCatalog.Catalogs.Add(asmCatalog);

        var hostContainer = new CompositionContainer(agrCatalog);
        hostContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    [Import(typeof(IMenu))]
    public IEnumerable<IMenu> Menus { get; set; }
    #endregion
```

I am importing a class that instances a `ToolStripMenuItem`. My export sample:

```
[Export(typeof(IMenu))]
public class CustomerMenu : IMenu
{
    #region Fields
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem CustomerMainMenu;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator mnuSeparator;
    private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem CustomersMenuItem;
    #endregion

    #region Init
    public CustomerMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // 
        // CustomerMenu
        // 
        this.CustomerMainMenu.DropDownItems.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
        this.mnuSeparator,
        this.CustomersMenuItem});
        this.CustomerMainMenu.Name = "CustomerMenu";
        this.CustomerMainMenu.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 20);
        this.CustomerMainMenu.Text = "Customer Menu";
        // 
        // toolStripMenuItem1
        // 
        this.mnuSeparator.Name = "toolStripMenuItem1";
        this.mnuSeparator.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(149, 6);
        // 
        // Customers
        // 
        this.CustomersMenuItem.Name = "Customers";
        this.CustomersMenuItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(152, 22);
        this.CustomersMenuItem.Text = "Customers";
    }

    #endregion

    #region Functions
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.CustomerMainMenu = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
        this.mnuSeparator = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripSeparator();
        this.CustomersMenuItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem();
    }

    #endregion
```

If `IMenu` is *not* required to implement `IEnumerable`, does anyone see something I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're importing a collection of exports, you need to be explicit about it by using the ImportMany attribute. Change your property attribute like this:

```
[ImportMany(typeof(IMenu))] 
public IEnumerable<IMenu> Menus { get; set; }
```

You should also be able to exclude the contract (the "typeof(Menu)" parameter) since you're importing the same type that was exported. Leave the contract on the Export attributes though.

```
[ImportMany] 
public IEnumerable<IMenu> Menus { get; set; }
```

Comment: bah..dang 5 minute timer. If you don't see the answer accepted in a few minutes...comment back.

Comment: I'm finally getting the hang of using MEF. So far, I'm a fan.

Comment: @dboarman Yeah I played with it quite a bit when it was in CTP form, and still dabble nowadays.